# How can I solve the problem of script blocking？

Tags: multithreading, unity-game-engine, design-patterns

I want to give users the ability to customize the behavior of game objects, but I found that unity is actually a single threaded program. If the user writes a script with circular statements in the game object, the main thread of unity will block, just like the game is stuck. How to make the update function of object seem to be executed on a separate thread?

[De facto execution order](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hWkUD.png)

[The logical execution sequence I want to implement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YpktZ.png)

Comment: dont use `While` in `Update` the whole game is big loop. `updates` gets called on every object every frame there is no need for `while`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement threading, but the UnityAPI is **NOT thread safe**, so anything you do outside of the main thread cannot use the UnityAPI. This means that you can do a calculation in another thread and get a result returned to the main thread, but you cannot manipulate GameObjects from the thread.

You do have other options though, for tasks which can take several frames, [you can use a coroutine](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html). This will also allow the method to wait without halting the main thread. It sounds like your best option is the [C# Jobs System](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/JobSystem.html). This system essentially lets you use multithreading and manages the threads for you.

Example from the Unity Manual:

```
public struct MyJob : IJob
{
    public float a;
    public float b;
    public NativeArray<float> result;

    public void Execute()
    {
        result[0] = a + b;
    }
}

// Create a native array of a single float to store the result. This example waits for the job to complete for illustration purposes
NativeArray<float> result = new NativeArray<float>(1, Allocator.TempJob);

// Set up the job data
MyJob jobData = new MyJob();
jobData.a = 10;
jobData.b = 10;
jobData.result = result;

// Schedule the job
JobHandle handle = jobData.Schedule();

// Wait for the job to complete
handle.Complete();

float aPlusB = result[0];

// Free the memory allocated by the result array
result.Dispose();
```

Comment: There is no need for `multithreading` to **customize the behavior of game objects** which is what OP wanted

Comment: @MiladQasemi OP is trying to allow user scripts which control GameObjects. If a user uses a loop which lasts for more than a frame, the main thread will halt.